# Export capacity from TFS iteration to Excel?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, alm

When working on an iteration on TFS one of the avaiable features is to set capacity for individual team members.

Is there a way to export this info to Excel (through a query, for exemple), to generate reports on team avaiability?

Article on MSDN about Capacity Planning on TFS: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/scale/capacity-planning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not (short of copy and paste).  The best way would be to use the api and export it yourself, maybe a little PowerShell script

[REST API - Capacity](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/work/capacity)